# Adding a web service to Xamarin Android VS 2019

Tags: c#, web-services, web, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to add a web service containing an SQL server connection to my Android page using Xamarin VS 2019.

First I opened this:

[image]

Then I wrote the url of the web service:

[image]

Finally, I got the error message:

[image]

Please help me with this?

I looked everywhere and Googled it a lot

Comment: Instead of relying only on images, please copy the full text of any code or error messages into your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I think you'll also need to explain a bit more what you are doing. "first I opened this" .. how did you get to that dialog? What is it part of? Visual Studio? Azure website? Its hard to tell what you are doing.

Comment: `.asmx` services are SOAP-based, and are entirely incompatible with OpenAPI, which is aligned with the REST paradigm - and REST is opposed to SOAP. Basically, what you're trying to do simply won't work: you'll need to use a different code-generator (for service client and proxy types) to generate C# classes from `.asmx` metadata, such as `svcutil.exe` and `wsdl.exe`

Comment: Thank you @Dai, can I have a link or something to start with this?

Comment: Given that your ASP.NET `.asmx` project doesn't look like you've invested much time in it _and_ because ASMX is horribly outdated and _effectively_ obsolete (but not _de-jure_ obsolete... before anyone corrects me) so I think it's a better idea just to create a new ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project instead of what you were doing before, as continuing down that path wouldn't really take you anywhere.

Comment: Simply I need to connect xamarin android vs2019 to local sql server database, that's it. where to begin, please?

Comment: No: mobile device apps should never connect directly to a database server (and DB server should never be exposed to the Internet either). That's why all mobile phone apps do everything through a web-service.

Comment: It's for test purposes in a close network with no internet. Then could you please share how I can connect through a web-service?

Comment: I suspect you underestimate the amount of effort required to build a web-service... that said, have you looked at using an OData system? (OData is basically a way to expose a database to web-service clients, at the expense of flexibility - but it's a good way to get something working in-a-pinch - just be prepared to outgrow it.